# How to query over a parent/child in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following parent/child example

```java
public class Parent implements Serializable{
    private Integer parentId;
    private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<Child>();

    public Parent(){}

    // getters and setters
}

public class Child implements Serializable{
    private Integer childId;
    private Parent parent;

    public Child(){}

    // getters and setters
}
```

XML files:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping package="com.dto">
    <class name="Parent" table="Parent">
        <id name="idParent" type="int" column="idParent">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <set name="childs" table="Childs" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="idParent" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="Child"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping package="com.dto">
    <class name="Child" table="Childs">
        <id name="idChild" type="int" column="idChild">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent" column="idParent" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem is if i run this query:

```java
ArrayList<Parent> parents = (ArrayList<Parent>) session.createQuery("from Parent p").list();
```

I got this: [parent], which is the result i want, but if i run this query:

```java
 ArrayList<Parent> parents = (ArrayList<Parent>) session.createQuery("from Parent p 
                                           inner join p.childs c 
                                           where parent.someField = someValue and 
                                           c.someField = someValue").list();
```

I got this: [ [parent, child] ] and i want to have this result: [parent]

How can i get the result i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a select clause (which is mandatory in JPQL, BTW):

```
select p from Parent p ...
```

Also, please don't assume that the query returns an ArrayList. It returns a List, and that's all you need to know:

```
List<Parent> parents = session.createQuery("...").list();
```

Finally, since it seems you're starting with Hibernate and are not maintaining a 10-year old codebase, you should use annotations rather than XML to map your entities. They're standard, safer and less verbose. XML was cool when Java was at version 4. It's now at version 8.

Comment: Supose every child contained in the parent's array has a boolean field called state. how can i do something like:
"from Parent p where p.child.state = true"
Is it possible ?